# DAX to measure number of boxes sold from different tables

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, dax

I am stuck in writing DAX formula to get total sold boxes in different tables. Now I have the following:

**Product_Lookup**

| Product Price | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 89 | 01-Mar-2023 | 28-Mar-2023 |
| 98 | 29-Mar-2023 | 01-Jan-2050 |

***I kept [End Date] as 2050 to measure all the prices above 28-Mar-2023 calculated as $98

I have **Calendar_Lookup** table starting from 2023 until 2026

I also have multiple transaction tables for different branches. But they look almost the same as:

**SalesOrders_10111**

| Branch ID | OrderDate | Order Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10111 | 01-Mar-2023 | 89 |
| 10111 | 25-Mar-2023 | 356 |
| 10111 | 30-Mar-2023 | 98 |
| 10111 | 31-Mar-2023 | 490 |

Is there a DAX formula to match dates between **ProductLookup[End Date]** and **SalesOrders_10111[OrderDate]**

if SalesOrders_10111[OrderDate] <= ProductLookup[End Date] then divide SalesOrders_10111[OrderDate] / ProductLookup[End Date] to get the total quantity of sold boxes.

Table Relations:

Calendar_lookup[Date](1) => SalesOrders_10111[OrderDate](*)

Calendar_lookup[Date](1) => ProductLookup[End Date](*)

I tried to use calculate & Filter functions but couldn't get column name since i am trying to add the expression under ProductLookup and even in SalesOrders_10111 i don't get column names in Product_Lookup

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not appending all the sales data to a single table. The other thing is that your Product lookup/dimension is a slowly changing dimension, and a slowly changing dimension has two keys - one that refers to "Product X" (the same product, regardless of price) and the other that refers to "Product X" during the time period when the price was the same. (as you have it, except each ID value is different).
you can use powerQuery merged to a calendar table to basically explode the interval into "a single record per product per day", and then you should be able to use this in your reports.

Comment: If I append all the records from different SalesOrders files into one query, wouldn't that create redundant data and lead to slowness? It will definitely solve the issue and make the things easier but I guess it will lead to a bigger file and slow load, am I right?

Comment: Thank you. I have restructured the tables and appended all sales data into one fact table with 5 lookup tables. I still didn't figure out how to do it. Ok.. My fact table has the following

Order Date | SalesAmount
01-Mar-23 | 89
02-Mar-23 | 267
03-Mar-23 | 445
.
.
.
20-Mar-23 | 196 <--- **We have changed the price here to 98 per box
 

(Calendar&PriceTracker_Lookup) has:
Date           | BoxPrice
01-Mar-23 | 89
.
.
20-Mar-23 | 98

How to create DAX formula (Check the date in Orders_Table and match with Calendar date then divide SalesAmount / Box price)

Answer (score 0):

> If I append all the records from different SalesOrders files into one
> query, wouldn't that create redundant data and lead to slowness?

Oh I think I get it. I think you're thinking in terms of an OLTP (not Data Warehouse) structure. Yes, there's some redundancy in the dimension tables, but it's a tradeoff. The redundancy makes grouping really simple, and that's the point.

So YES, make one TALL fact table. (It should consist of numeric values and foreign keys, nothing else).

The other wrinkle here is that you many have a slowly changing dimension (The Product table where some attributes change over time, and you need to basically keep those... like Price).

Comment: Did you record in each Sales record (in Sales fact table) the number of boxes sold?